# Python 3 ignores metaclass directive?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiple-inheritance, metaclass, abc

***Edited***

I have 2 classes inheriting from `ABC`, and a third class inheriting from both, each in a different file. Tried to provide the metaclass of `ABCMeta` to the last class, to resolve the conflict of metaclasses, but it fails with the same

```
"TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases"
```

Why does python ignore the metaclass directive in this case, and how to resolve it?

file A:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class A(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def method1(self):
       pass
```

file B:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class B(ABC):      
    @abstractmethod
    def method2(self):
       pass
```

file C:

```
import A
import B
class C(A,B,metaclass=ABCMeta):
    def method1(self):
       pass
    def method2(self):
       pass
```

Comment: Works for me (Python 3.6).

Comment: what is `ABC` ??? Please post a proper MCVE

Comment: @OlivierMelançon when I posted this comment there was no import of ABC (check the post history).

Comment: I added the relevant imports to make it clearer

Comment: Cannot reproduce. I don't get any errors in python3.5.2.

Comment: Yes, it works! Thanks @Matthias, I didn't try this MCVE first myself :-( the problem was with wrong import !!!
classes A & B were in files A and B accordingly, and I tried to inherit from A which is a module probably, not a class :) so after importing them properly the problem was resolved. Funny that python gives this missleading in this case error, though it probably has no way to know better :)

Comment: I've edited the question, with the precise scenario for anyone who encounters this is the future. Thanks for your help @Matthias!

Comment: @feelnow: So basically [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35367340/364696), but with metaclasses thrown in?

Comment: @ShadowRanger, yes, same problem, different symptoms (error), really confused me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem stems from wrong import.
file C should be:

```
from A import A
from B import B
class C(A,B):
   def method1(self):
      pass
   def method2(self):
      pass
```

Credit should go to @Matthias & @Giacomo Alzetta, who pointed out that the MCVE works for them.