# super() takes at most 2 arguments (8 given)

Tags: python, python-3.x, super

I have error

```
super()` takes at most 2 arguments (8 given)
```

What did I do wrong?

I read this [importing module causes `TypeError: module.__init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35367871/355230)
but it did not help me.

```
class PersonBase:
    def __init__(self, person_id="", first_name="", second_name="", birth_date="", name="", sex="", relation="", educations=[], works=[]):
        """ Common fields of all person types"""
        
        self.person_id = person_id
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.second_name = second_name
        ....

class Person(PersonBase):
    """ PersonBase and list of Realive objects"""
    
    def __init__(self, person_id="", first_name="", second_name="", birth_date="", name="", sex="", relation="", educations=[], works=[], relatives=[]):
        super(PersonBase).__init__(person_id, first_name, second_name, birth_date, name, sex, relation, educations)
        self.relatives = relatives
```

Comment: why are you passing `super(PersonBase)` to super?? Just use `super()`.

Comment: You don't mean `super(PersonBase)`. That would be the super of `PersonBase`. You should just need to use `super()`.

Comment: The correct way to use the full form would be `super(Person, self).__init__(person_id, first_name, second_name, birth_date, name, sex, relation, educations)` however, you should just use `super().__init__(person_id, first_name, second_name, birth_date, name, sex, relation, educations)`